# Error opening a Visual Studio 2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio C# project at work that I took home so I could work on it at home.    At home when I click on the .sln file I get the following error -

> "The selected file is a solution file, but was created by a newer
>   version of this application and cannot be opened"

But the Visual Studio at my work is and the one at home are both VS2010.  In fact they were installed off the same DVD.

In Help About the one at work reads

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

The one at home says

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 RTMRel

What is the significance of the RTM -vs- SP1 and why am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check if you have windows updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTM means Release-To-Manufacture, this indicates that it is the version directly from the CD; SP1 indicates that the first service pack for visual studio has been installed.

The simplest means of resolving this issue would be to update your home install to VS2010 Service Pack 1.

Alternatively, you can probably resolve the issue by recreating the solution file and manually adding your existing projects.